# Как правильно написать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"... информация представлена в приложении Вашего письма" или "...информация представлена в приложении к Вашему письму".

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, второе. Приложение бывает к чему-то. Например, "приложение к закону о печати".